# ECMA-48 に記述がある、 data component の概念が何を表しているのかわからない

Tags: 端末

[一般的な「端末(エミュレーター)」の仕様は？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/21995/754) のコメントで紹介された、[ECMA-48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)の規約を読んでいました。この規約は、制御コード(Control Function) について記述されているようですが、その中で規約が想定する device (端末？) として、"Presentation Component" のみを持つ場合と、 "Data Component" と "Presentation Component" の両方を持つ bidirectional な場合を想定していると記述がありました。

Presentation Component は、制御コードと印字文字(graphical character)を受け取って人間が読める形で出力する抽象装置であると理解できたのですが、 Data Component が何を言わんとしているのかがさっぱり理解できませんでした。

6.1.5 Relationship between active data position and active presentation position より、

> In a bi-directional device, if it has a presentation component and a
>   data component, the active presentation position is the character
>   position in the presentation component that corresponds to the active
>   data position in the data component. Because of the possible
>   differences between character progression and character path, as in
>   some bi-directional environments, the coordinates of the active data
>   position in the data component and of the active presentation position
>   in the presentation component may differ.

かろうじて、 Data Component と Presentation Component の位置がずれている場合があるというのは理解できたのですが、それが具体的にどんな場合なのかが想像できていません。端末において、このずれが発生している状態とは、どのような状態ですか？

Comment: [Black BerryのECMA-48準拠のエミュレータのソース](https://github.com/mordak/Term48/blob/master/ecma48.c)では、data componentは行単位の情報を保持しておくバファみたいです。ホストからLFを送るとして、まず最初にDEVICE COMPONENT SELECT MODE
(DCSM)でPresentation ComponentかData Componentかを選択してからline feedの操作を行うなどという使われ方がされていました。でも画面の表示とバッファが一致していないケースを想像するのは難しいですね。複数ページのバッファを保持できるような端末なら表示内容と違うというのはありえそうです。一昔前の汎用機の端末はホストと毎回通信しなくても、ユーザーがページを切り替えて見ることができるみたいです。（その世代じゃないですけどね！）

Comment: 画面の表示領域がPresentation componentの大きさだとして、スクロールできるようにバッファを画面より広くしていたら、それぞれの座標は（連動してはいるものの）一致するとは限りません。ただそういう意味合いならbi-directional device関係ないのではという疑問が…。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

data component/presentation component は bi-directional text のサポートの為に[ECMA TR/53](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/techreports/E-TR-053.htm)を元に導入された概念です。

data component は入力されたデータがそのまま保存される領域で、
presentation component は実際に画面に表示される形式になります。

例えば`ABC<SRS 1>def<SRS 0>GHI`という入力があった場合、(`<SRS>`は書字方向の反転の制御シーケンス)
data component 内のデータは

> ABCdefGHI

となりますが presentation component では

> ABCfedGHI

となります。(デフォルトの書字方向がLeft to Rightの場合)

詳細は [ECMA TR/53](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/techreports/E-TR-053.htm) を読んでみて下さい。

Comment: そういうことだったのですねぇ。てっきり双方向通信の意味だと思っていました。ツイッター見ましたけど、VT100お持ちとは！