# MacのemacsでC->のキー入力方法について

Tags: emacs

mark-multipleを使いたくて、emacsにインストールしました。
設定は以下のようにしたのですが、

```
(require 'mark-more-like-this)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<") 'mark-previous-like-this)
(global-set-key (kbd "C->") 'mark-next-like-this)
```

実際にMacのemacs上で`Control + .` 押すとピリオドが打ち込まれてしまいます。
どのキーを押したら良いのでしょうか。

Githubページ
https://github.com/magnars/mark-multiple.el

Answer (score 1):

端末(ターミナル)の上で動かす emacs での話ですか？

端末は、その種類によっては、 `C-.` や `C->` は正しく扱えません。特に、 mac にデフォルトで入っている端末では確実に無理です。参考: [一般的な「端末(エミュレーター)」の仕様は？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/21995/754)

なので、 [gnu emacs for mac](https://emacsformacosx.com/) を GUI アプリとして起動して使うであったり、 xterm 上で動かすであったりなどの工夫が必要なはずです。

Comment: はい、macのターミナルの上で動かすemacsです。
そのままでは使えないということなんですね。

Answer (score 1):

Yuki Inoueさんの回答のとおり、環境によっては`C-.`や`C->`は正しく扱えない場合があります。しかし、正しく扱える環境でも、`C->`や`C-<`を入力したいのであれば追加でShiftも押す必要があります。(単なる`>`を入力するときに`Shift + .`を押すと思いますが、それに`Control`が増えるということです)