# tmux + emacsで、<C-.>、<C-/>のキーが反応しない

Tags: emacs, tmux

OS: OSX Yosemite

tmux上で、以下コマンドでemacsを立ち上げています。

```
$ emacs -nw
```

Redo/Undoを、`C-.`、`C-/`に割り当てていますが、キーを入力しても反応がありません。

`describe-key`でキーバインドを確かめようとしましたが、
`C-.`、`C-/`どちらも入力できませんでした。

他のキーだと、入力できてキーバインドを確認することはできました。

上記の状況に心当たりがあり、解決方法をご存知の方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？

Comment: 関連する質問：http://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/21979/2391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teminal として xterm を使うという条件であれば、Emacs で `C-.` などを入力できる様になるかもしれません。したがって、Mac OS X で X Window System アプリケーションが利用できない場合、以下は意味がなくなりますのでご承知おき下さい。

こちらの環境は以下の通りです。

```
    OS: Linux 4.4.0
Distro: Ubuntu 16.04
 xterm: 322
  tmux: 2.1
 Emacs: 25.1(snapshot version)
```

xterm には `modifyOtherKeys` という resource が用意されています。

> **modifyOtherKeys (class ModifyOtherKeys)**
>
> Like modifyCursorKeys, tells xterm to construct an escape sequence for other keys (such as "2") when modified by Control-, Alt- or Meta-modifiers. This feature does not apply to function keys and well-defined keys such as ESC or the control keys. The default is "0":
>
> ```
>  0  disables this feature.
>  1  enables this feature for keys except for those with well-known behavior,
>     e.g., Tab, Backarrow and some special control character cases, e.g.,
>     Control-Space to make a NUL.
>  2  enables this feature for keys including the exceptions listed.
> ```

ここでは `1` に設定します(`2` に設定すると全ての escape sequence が「そのままの状態で」出力されてしまいます)。具体的には `$HOME/.xresources` に以下を追加します。

```
XTerm*eightBitInput:    false
XTerm*metaSendsEscape:  true
XTerm*modifyOtherKeys:  1
```

設定をリロードします。

```
$ xrdb -load $HOME/.xresources
```

ここでは `$HOME/.xresources` としていますが、任意のファイルで構いません。

次に `$HOME/.tmux.conf` に以下を追加します。

```
set -g xterm-keys on
```

これによって 上記の xterm resource に tmux の動作が対応する様になります。

なお、こちらの環境では `C-.` と `C-/` が効く様になりましたが、`C-;(semicolon)` が無効のままです。

Answer (score 3):

端末エミュレータ上で`C-.`等の修飾キー操作を入力することは難しかったと思います。

代替案としては、Ctrlキーを押したように見せかけるキーバインド `C-x @ c` (`event-apply-control-modifier`) を利用する手があります。ただし、Redo/Undoのように多用するコマンドを呼び出すのには扱いやすいキー操作ではないかもしれません。

- `C-.` を入力したい→ `C-x @ c .`
- `C-/` を入力したい→ `C-x @ c /`

参考：ターミナル上のEmacsで本来使えない"Ctrlキー+何か"を使う方法
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/sugyan/20120228/1330392943

また、リンク先の記事ではiTerm2のキーボードショートカット設定で`C-;`を`C-x @ c ;`に変換することもできるそうです。